# Linux where does zip place the newly created zip file?

Tags: linux, zip

Looking to zip up a folder on my linux box ie `zip -r9 test /var/www/html/` where does that resulting test.zip file end up? in my pwd? I still want to leave the contents of /var/www/html intact.

Comment: the lack of man zip not stating that at least anywhere I could find it and I knew if I asked I'd get the direct answer here!

Comment: Ok, you are not able to read the man page but you also cannot test it? Meaning `ls` was not possible to execute?

Comment: no I didn't want to actually execute the command until I knew for sure how it was going to respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it creates zip in your current working directory.

Comment: asked and answered! - thx!!

Answer (score 0):

True is that you are free to specify relative or absolute paths like you wish.

```
zip test.zip path/to/files
```

will place test.zip in the current working directory.

```
zip /foo/bar/test.zip path/to/files
```

will place test.zip in `/foo/bar`